# Syntax error on tokens, delete tokens

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I want to implement Timer Schedule on my class, and its giving me a error

> " Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens "
>
> public String getTemperature() throws RemoteException,
>   MalformedURLException, IOException, NotBoundException

```
public class HelloWorldService extends TimerTask {


@Override
public void run(){

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getTemperature() throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException, IOException, NotBoundException {
    String result = null;

    try {

        Client client = Client.create();

        WebResource webResource = client
           .resource("http://localhost:8080/RobotAutomation/webapi/robot/get");

        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("text/plain")
                   .get(ClientResponse.class);

        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
            + response.getStatus());
        }

        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

        System.out.println("Output from Application 3  \n");
        System.out.println(output);

        result = String.format("Output from Application 3: %s", output);
        if (!output.equals(null))
            System.out.println(" -------------------------TEST1----------------------------------------- ");
             move.doSomething();
                /*test();
                test2();*/
      } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }

    return result;

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks like `getTemperature()` method is written inside `run()` method.

**You can't put methods inside of methods.**

```
@Override
public void run(){

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getTemperature() throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException, IOException, NotBoundException {
    String result = null;


// code..
}
}
```

**move your `getTemperature()` method out of `run()` method ,** 
like this.

```
@Override
    public void run(){

   // run method logic..
   }
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getTemperature() throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException, IOException, NotBoundException {
    String result = null;


// getTemperature logic..
}
```

Comment: Could you explain me, in Detail ?

Comment: what is the solution for this ?